# Google Cloud APIs usage data by projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to programmatically get data similar to APIs overview of Google CLoud dashboard. Specifically, I'm interested in the list of APIs enabled for the project and their usage/error stats for some predefined timeframe. I belive there's an API for that but I struggle to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no API that gives you a report similar to the one you can see through the Google Cloud Console.

The [Compute API can retrieve some quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/get) with the `get` method but it's somewhat limited (only Compute Engine quotas) and, for what I understood from your question, not quite what you're looking for.

However, I've found in Google's Issue Tracker a [feature request that's close to what you're asking for](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111004474).

If you would need something more specific or want to do the feature request yourself, check the ["Report feature requests" documentation](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) and create your own. The GCP team will take a look at it to evaluate and consider implementation.